# eclipse default view when hitting breakpoint

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

When I hit a breakpoint in Eclipse the view automatically changes to show the debug on top, even if I was looking at something else, specifically the variables view. Is there a way to make eclipse show variables as the default view when you hit a breakpoint, or better yet not change the view at all?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Right Corner of Eclipse close the view if u don't want]

You can do something like this.